# Keep always the all stars inside a div

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a div inside an image and within that div I want to put five stars.

My problem is that when I reduce the size, the stars come out of the box :(

Is there a way to keep them always in the box, even when the screen size is small?

**html**

```
<div class="abc">
    <div class="def">
        <img class="img-fluid Images" src="https://i.ibb.co/3p3D4h6/dmitry-bayer-276d-F1-RG67-Q-unsplash.jpg">
        <div class="row boxImage">
            <star-rating value="4" totalstars="5"
                 (rate)="Rate($event)"></star-rating>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't it because you fix their size at 30px?

Comment: Even with% or not setting the value, the same happens

Comment: What are you reducing the size of?  How do you reduce it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the CSS of class `boxImage` you have set the width to 40%. Read about CSS width property here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width

Notice how it says :

> <\percentage>
>       Defines the width as a percentage of the containing block's width.

Thus, your star rating component is always as wide as 40% of the resized picture, leaving not enough space for the 5 starts.

You should use this value : max-content https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width#max-content :

```
 .boxImage {
    background-color: white;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 50px;
    width: max-content;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 1;
    max-width: 360px;     
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 16px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Take care of the different browser support (see link).

Comment: @Paulsk Great :) If your issue is now solved, please mark it as answered in order to help tidying StackOverflow. Thanks.